# How to redirect all files in a directory to another in root via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all files (whether it exists or not) in **/user** directory on my site to a file named **temp.php** in root directory via .htaccess.

For example, if a user enter **user/send.php** or **user/** or **user/send** (It may be that not Exists at all), all redirect to temp.php.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Does this redirect includes images? CSS? JavaScript? as well?

Comment: no all files in this directory are php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ http://domain.com/temp.php [R,L]
```

Comment: I am new to unix. Can you please explain whats the use of [R,L]?

Comment: These are flags (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) -- L|last, R|redirect