# Redirect all html files from subfolder to same html files in root

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need the code to 301 redirect all .html files from a folder to their html correspondents in the root folder:
Something like

```
http://www.mysite.ro/catalog/.html
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.ro/.html
```

But I want that all .html files (and only .html) to be redirected, taking in consideration that:

1. all files from subfolder have already correspondents in the root
   folder
2. there are still files in the /catalog/ folder.

I can't use full folder redirect because that will interfere with the remaining files from the subfolder.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all files in a directory to another in root via htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372931/how-to-redirect-all-files-in-a-directory-to-another-in-root-via-htaccess)

Comment: I already tried that, but interfere with remaining files from subfolder.

Comment: so you should put this htaccess file in that particular folder only, in your case "catalog" folder

Comment: I don't want to redirect all files to a specific file (like in your answer), but in pairs: catalog/1.html to 1.html, catalog/file2.html to file2.html and so on.

Comment: for that you can   " /.+\.html$ " at place of "  /(.*)$ ".

Comment: Like in `RewriteRule /.+\.html$ http://www.mysite.ro/catalog/$1 [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: In your case it should be  `RewriteRule /.+\.html$ http://www.mysite.ro/$1 [R=301,L]'  and keep this .htaccess file inside catalog folder.

Comment: I've got a 404 error...

Comment: What is the URL u r getting...?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it right now, the thing is that perhaps some cache misguided me before, but the root .htaccess is working and what I want is working. Don't ask how, I'm also confused. I'm using opencart, but I'm kinda new to it.